# Android Popup Window crashes application

Tags: android, menu, arraylist, android-manifest, popupwindow

Hi I am new to android and I am trying to make a menu for restaurant.  My application will display a list of items along with their thumb sized image in the image button. There are multiple items in the List. When a user clicks on the Image button another windows pop up showing the Image. Depending on which button is clicked the Image should pop out. I used switch statement for the purpose. That is if button one is pressed R.drawable.imag01 should pass on to the popup window class.

Appetizer.java

```
package com.example.thumbnailzoom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Appetizer extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageButton ibAp1;
int img;
PopupWin pop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.appetizer);
DisplayComponent();

ibAp1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void DisplayComponent() {
ibAp1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Ap1);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.Ap1:
img = R.drawable.appetimg01;
pop.setPopupImage(img);
pop.displayImage();
break;
}
}

}
```

Appetizer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/appetizerTitle1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:text="Canape Assortments       "
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/appetizerPrice1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:text="1.800"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/appetizerDes1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_weight="20"
android:text="6 pieces of mini toasted bread topped with smoked salmon prawn and turkey"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textStyle="italic" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/Ap1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="80"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/appetimg01" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

PopupWin.java

```
package com.example.thumbnailzoom;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class PopupWin extends Activity {
private ImageView img;
private int imgValue;
private Button bDismiss;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void setPopupImage(int img){
imgValue = img;
}

public void displayImage() {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
img.setImageResource(imgValue);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Button bDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
bDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
popupWindow.dismiss();
}
});
}
}
```

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dim_back" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dim_back"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="20sp"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/dismiss"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
android:text="Go Back"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thumbnailzoom"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.thumbnailzoom.Appetizer"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.example.thumbnailzoom.PopupWin"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The Code works when written together but I want to separate the code of Image popup from the items list. This code will display the Menu list but when I click on the thumbnail the application crashes. What am I missing please guide. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance. And sorry for the newbie sloppy code.

Comment: Always post a full stack trace from logcat with any crashing bug you post here.

Comment: it is giving me this errorDescription Resource Path Location Type
This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view popup.xml /ThumbnailZoom/res/layout line 14 Android Lint Problem

Comment: That's not the crash log, its not an error.  It's a warning.  You have something inefficient in your layout, but it isn't the problem here.

Comment: it is may be something in the manifest that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

you must be getting `NullPointerException` because in `Apetizer` Activity you are not intilizing `PopupWin pop`; and your are accessing pop object in `onclick` method without intializing

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your `PopupWin` as a separate Activity, but are not launching it as an Activity. You cannot create objects like `PopupWin pop;` and then use them like any other Activity. Additionally, you are not initializing `pop` anywhere, so you will run into a `NullPointerException` anyways, regardless of what kind of class it is.

Now, assuming you do initialize it: If you do this, then your Activity's onCreate() is never called, and its context etc. isn't created as it doesn't follow the Activity lifecycle. Therefore, whenever you try to use something like `LayoutInflater`, you will get an exception because `getBaseContext()` will return null.

So fix this, start the `PopupWin` using:

```
case R.id.Ap1:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopupWin.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

You can pass the image resource you want to use as an Intent Extra and retrieve it on the other end

Comment: i wrote intent in the onCreate method of of PopupWin and described it as a seperate activity in manifest. I also initialized pop in appetizer under displaycomponent() method of Appetizer. but the application crashes now. I am having trouble with holding on to concepts of adnroid. It is very different from C++ and java

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to open popup window

```
public void OpenPopWindow(View v)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
     View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupmenu, null);
       PopupWindow popupwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false); 

             popupwindow .setAnimationStyle(R.style.DialogAnimation);  
             popupwindow .setWidth(display.getWidth());  
             popupwindow .showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);  
             popupwindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black));}
```